# 1st Sept coming before 31st Aug in bar chart ordering by date in Zeppelin, how to fix please?

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, impala, apache-zeppelin

In Zeppelin I have a simple bar chart of value (Y axis) against date (X axis), which was working fine until the new start of this month (today), when it put "1 Sep" before "31 Aug". I am ordering by the date string (as that's the string I need to display on the chart).

[image: Chart image showing most recent dates in the wrong place]

Query:

```
%impala
SELECT FROM_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', concat(replace(my_timestamp,'"',''), "Z")), 'd MMM HH:mm') AS hours, COUNT(my_number) AS "number per hour"
FROM my_table
WHERE unix_timestamp(my_timestamp) > (unix_timestamp(now()) - 86400)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
LIMIT 24;
```

I realise the issue is due to the alphanumeric comparison of the date strings. I thought I could fix it by adding a third column for the unix_timestamp() of the date then ordering by that, but that gives a grouping error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): unix_timestamp(my_timestamp)
```

for this query:

```
%impala
SELECT FROM_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', concat(replace(my_timestamp,'"',''), "Z")), 'd MMM HH:mm') AS hours, COUNT(my_number) AS "number per hour", unix_timestamp(my_timestamp)
FROM my_table
WHERE unix_timestamp(my_timestamp) > (unix_timestamp(now()) - 86400)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 ASC
LIMIT 24;
```

How to fix please to get chart in correct order?

Comment: The error is due to the fact that you are trying to select a column/calculated value, that is not part of your GROUPing. But can't you just order by `my_timestamp`? (Not sure if that'll give the same error.)

Comment: @CBroe OK, thanks, not sure how to fix the group by in this case then. But I did just change the "order by" line to: "ORDER BY my_timestamp ASC" and I removed ", unix_timestamp(my_timestamp)" from the SELECT clause, but I am still getting the same grouping error...

Comment: Adding `my_timestamp ` to your grouping is probably not a good idea, that'll have a different granularity, than your formatted value. But you could just add a different formatting, like `09-01` for `1 Sep`, and then include that in your grouping - since both values are directly related, that should not affect the result at all. Or you could just use your existing query as a sub-query, and then apply ordering in the outer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate additional column in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format (same granularity as hours but in sortable format) and add it to groupby (before hours column) and to the order by (instead of hours column) :

```
SELECT FROM_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', concat(replace(my_timestamp,'"',''), "Z")), 'd MMM HH:mm') AS hours, 
       FROM_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', concat(replace(my_timestamp,'"',''), "Z")), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as dt,
       COUNT(my_number) AS "number per hour"
FROM my_table
WHERE unix_timestamp(my_timestamp) --also it seems Z should be removed, etc 
      > (unix_timestamp(now()) - 86400)
GROUP BY dt, hours
ORDER BY dt
LIMIT 24;
```